# What strategy to take if MongoDB is down and operations are pending

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a List where each Employee has a Manager assigned. So for each object has a Manager reference in it, which is not a manager id, but a set of fields by which we can identify a manager.

Each Manager object has list of references of Employees

So classes look like this

```
Class Manager {

ObjectId _id;

//some attributes

List<Employees> employees;

LocalDateTime createdOn;

}
```

```
Class Employee {

ObjectId _id

//some attributes

Manager manager; //Having only attributes but not ObjectId of manager

LocalDateTime createdOn;

}
```

We have done this because names and some attributes of this manager can be changed and hence a new Manager Object can be introduced in the Manager collection and then all the existing employees will now belong to the new manager object. That’s how our structure is.

While querying, we will get attributes of a Manager, and we return back List of Employees of the manager who is latest according to the attributes and a createdOn field

So the problem which I’m facing is:

While saving a new List of Employees which belong to a new Manager, I first save all the Employees using insertMany() function of mongoClient. Then I save the Manager using insert().

If after saving the Employee list and before saving the Manager, something bad happened to Mongo and Db is down so I won’t be able to save the Manager, hence all Employees will now be orphaned.

**What strategies I can follow in order to ensure that when MongoDB comes up again, I can first store all the pending objects and then continue with the rest of the operations.**

I'm using SpringBoot 2 with Raw Mongo Java driver 3.8.0 and Java 8

I have tried Mongo retry writes option but that only tries once

Comment: @mtj actually I tried using transactions but it is only supported in replica sets and not in a sharded cluster. Mine is a sharded cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, the following two options spring to mind.

- Have a backup data store that you write to if MongoDB is down (e.g. another instance of Mongo, free-form text files, PostgreSQL), and automatically switch to it. You might have to manually put that data back into Mongo afterwards, and then switch Mongo writes back on, but if Mongo going down is quite rare, this is probably acceptable.
- Put a queue between your main app and a worker process whose sole purpose is to write to Mongo. If Mongo goes down, the worker process stops, and the failed write stays on the queue. When Mongo comes back up, worker process is restarted, and all will be well.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 4.0, mongodb supports transactions. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/ and the java examples. Note that the 3.8 driver already contains all necessary methods, support is just a question of the database server version.